# Changing Button image after response from server

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

Am working on an App in which implements a FOLLOW Button inside a View-pager.

when the user clicks the FOLLOW Button the button should change to FOLLOWING after getting success response from the server.

Although i have implemented it ...The button image doesn't change after the click.it has a very unusual behavior.

It sometimes shows FOLLOWING after the activity is reloaded or the pager slides.
Below is my code..

```
    package comend.com.comendify.adapters;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import comend.com.comendify.R;
    import comend.com.comendify.activity.ActViewUserProfile;
    import comend.com.comendify.models.Home;
    import comend.com.comendify.models.Tags;
    import comend.com.comendify.models.User;
    import        comend.com.comendify.serverCommunication.WebServerSetGetUserActivities;
    import comend.com.comendify.utility.RoundedImageView;
    import comend.com.comendify.utility.UserJSONUtils;
    import comend.com.comendify.utility.Utils;

   /**
    * Created by qamar on 14-03-2016.
    */
   public class ImageViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
   public static final String TAG =    ImageViewPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
   Context mContext;
   LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
   private ArrayList<String> imageList;
   private ArrayList<Home> home_arrayList;
   private String loggedInUserId;
   private Button btnFollow,btnUnFollow;
   int resourceId;
   int START_INDEX;
   private User userLogged;
   private View itemView ;
   Boolean val =true;
   private boolean isFollowing = true;
   boolean isIconChange;

   public ImageViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList, int START_INDEX, int resoursceId, ArrayList<Home> home_arrayList) {
    mContext = context;
    this.imageList =imageList;
    this.home_arrayList = home_arrayList;
    this.resourceId = resoursceId;
    this.START_INDEX = START_INDEX;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    loggedInUserId = Utils.getLoggedInUserId(mContext);
    Log.d(TAG,"In ImageViewAdapter: " +START_INDEX+" "+home_arrayList);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    if(resourceId == R.layout.item_show_image_pager) {
        return imageList.size();
    }
        return home_arrayList.size();

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    if(resourceId == R.layout.item_home_pager_profile){
        return view ==((RelativeLayout)object);
    }
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"In InstantiateItem" + position);

    if(resourceId == R.layout.item_show_image_pager) {
        itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_show_image_pager, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "In viewImage " + position + " " + START_INDEX);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_asi_image);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageList.get(position))
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.logo_splash)
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(itemView);
    }else if(resourceId == R.layout.item_home_pager_header){
        Log.d(TAG, "In homeImageHeader " + position + " " + START_INDEX);
        itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_pager_header, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_home_image_header);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(String.valueOf(home_arrayList.get(position).getEnt_image()))
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.logo_splash)
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int fragId = 2;

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActViewUserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra("item_id", home_arrayList.get(position).ent_id);
                intent.putExtra("frag_id", fragId);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "complete item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }else if(resourceId == R.layout.item_home_pager_profile){
        //here is the problem in yhis layout
        Log.d(TAG, "In homeUserProfile  " +home_arrayList);
        itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_pager_profile,container,false);
        //function for setting all the elements of item
        setUserCommends(itemView, position);
        container.addView(itemView);



        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG,"In ItemView Clicked");
                int fragId = 3;

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActViewUserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra("commend_id", home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_commend_id());
                intent.putExtra("frag_id", fragId);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "complete item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if(resourceId ==R.layout.item_show_image_pager) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }else if(resourceId == R.layout.item_home_pager_profile){
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
        //container.removeViewAt(position);
        Log.d(TAG,"In destroy Item " +container.getChildCount());

    }

}

//method for setting all the elements
private void setUserCommends(View itemView, final int position){
    Log.d(TAG,"In homeprofile setUserCommends " +position );
    //Log.d(TAG,"In homeProfile1"  +home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_product_image() +" "+home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_image());
    ImageView ivProductImage        = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_hpp_product_pic);
    TextView  tvProductName         = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hpp_product_name);
    TextView  tvProductDesc         = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hpp_description);
    RoundedImageView  ivUserImage   = (RoundedImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_hpp_user_profile_pic);
    TextView   tvUserName           = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hpp_profile_name);
    btnFollow                       = (Button)    itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_hpp_follow);
  //  btnUnFollow   = (Button)    itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_hpp_unfollow);

    userLogged = new User();
    userLogged.setmUserName(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_name());
    userLogged.setmImageUrl(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_image());
    userLogged.setmFirstName(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_name());

    //checking for the buttons for each slides or when the screen first turns up
    if(home_arrayList.get(position).getIs_following()== 0){
        Log.d(TAG, "In check if " + home_arrayList.get(position).getIs_following());
        btnFollow.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.profile_follow, 0, 0, 0);

    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "In check else " + home_arrayList.get(position).getIs_following());
        btnFollow.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.profile_following, 0, 0, 0);

    }

    if(!home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_product_image().isEmpty()) {
        setImageWithPicasso(ivProductImage, home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_product_image());
    }
    if(!home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_image().isEmpty()){
        setImageWithPicasso(ivUserImage, home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_image());
    }
    tvProductName.setText(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_product_name());
    tvProductDesc.setText(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_commend_review());
    tvUserName.setText(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_name());

    ivUserImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG,"In userImage Clicked");
            int fragId = 1;

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActViewUserProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("user_id", home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_id());
            intent.putExtra("frag_id", fragId);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "complete item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    //isFollowing = false;
    //puttong the clickListener on the follow button
    btnFollow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG,"In btnFollow Clicked");
            //isIconC =!isIconChange;


                if (isFollowing =true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "in isFollowing");
                    isFollowing =false;
                    btnFollow.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.profile_follow, 0, 0, 0);
                    unFollowUser(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_id(), position);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "in isNotFollowing");
                    isFollowing = true;
                    btnFollow.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.profile_following, 0, 0, 0);
                    btnFollow.setText("UNFOLLOW");
                    //btnFollow.setEnabled(false);
                    followerUser(home_arrayList.get(position).getUser_id(), position);

                }
        }
    });

}

private void  setImageWithPicasso(ImageView imageView, String user_product_image){
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(user_product_image)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.logo_splash)
            .into(imageView);
}

//Method for Following user
private void followerUser(String user_id, int position) {
    final int FOLLOW_TAG = 0;
    UserJSONUtils userJSONUtils = new UserJSONUtils(mContext);
    String json =userJSONUtils. setDataToJson(userLogged,user_id);
    //call the method to follow
    callToServerToFollow(json, FOLLOW_TAG,position);

}

 //method for UnFollowing user
private void unFollowUser(String user_id, int position){
    final int  UNFOLLOW_TAG = 1;
    UserJSONUtils userJSONUtils = new UserJSONUtils(mContext);
    String json = userJSONUtils.setDataToJson(userLogged,user_id);
    //calling the method to follow
    callToServerToFollow(json, UNFOLLOW_TAG,position);
}

// method for calling server
public void callToServerToFollow(String json,int TAG_FOLL,int position){


    WebServerSetGetUserActivities webServerSetGetUserActivities = new WebServerSetGetUserActivities(mContext,btnFollow,btnUnFollow,null,null);
    webServerSetGetUserActivities.addFollowUnFollow(json, TAG_FOLL, Tags.ACT_TAG.ACT_HOME_FEED,home_arrayList,position);
}
```

}

really appreciate any help.

Comment: what are you trying to do is setting up button to success with an image on server response. is it ????

Comment: yeah Pramod..after i get a success response from server my Follow button changes its image to Following  Note:- my button resides inside a view pager

Answer (score 0):

Note, Fragments state on ViewPager are being initialize a Fragment before.
that is if three fragments A,B,C are use on ViewPager, B state is initialize on A while on user view, C also those the same when B is on user View. 
There are two way to solve this 
1) use A Fragment to implement the request method for response and set a public boolean to get response result true, then on B fragment where the button event is needed, check for boolean result.
2) In your AppController class check for result from A fragment and set to B fragment. This will always keep the result as it is even when the app is onPause.
check this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ for implementing AppController class.